# Jenkins update procedure without breaking it

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

I'd like to get some recommendations and ideas for updating my closed environment jenkins(no internet connection) and all it's plug-ins.

My current version is 2.19.4-1.1

- What problems may accure?
- Do I need to do it in small jumps it just update to the latest version?
- What do I need to take under consideration besides the java update to java 8?
- Any ideas for updating the plug-ins in a closed environment so I don't need to update them one by one?
- Do you have recommendations for a multi master architecture?
- What plugin should I use for it?

The env has 1500 jobs. Any best practices?

Comment: My experience with Jenkins is that something will almost always break. In Jenkins core, plugins, something you never thought about, etc. My advice is to take a backup, restore it to a new system, perform the upgrade, and test it out to see what happens. If you have a specific problem, then follow up here with that issue.

Comment: Thanks!
Ill try it out.